# Facebook og:image issue

Tags: html, facebook, webforms

I've got problem with the facebook image. My image is not being displayed on sharing, while on google+ is working fine. The facebook debugger is giving me the following message:

og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'https://marketsrally.com/images/video/text-banner.png' will be used instead.

My og tags:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="388490671332868" />
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<meta property="og:title" content="Markets Rally" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://marketsrally.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://marketsrally.com/images/socialLogo.jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="313" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Markets Rally" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Join us and get a pole position on the Markets Rally" />
<meta name="description" content="The World Leaders in online Binary Options, for trading on indices, commodities, currencies and stocks." />
<meta name="keywords" content="https://marketsally.com binary options, digital options, trade options, options trading, options, binary trading, easy profit, quick profit, easy trading, simple trading, forex, forex trading, online trading, nasdaq, dow jones, dax, crude oil, gold" />
```

The link to the site:

https://marketsrally.com/

My image is around 300 pixels width and height, and the link is valid. It is jpg format, although I tried with PNG. What could be the problem?

Comment: P.S. Update: It seems after I refreshed the site, fb issue was fixed. But now google+ is displaying wrong image, and LinkedIn is showing old image and description. How can I debug them like fb or refresh their presentation?(google and linkedin)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://beta.beantin.se/clearing-linkedin-link-sharing-preview-cache/ Apparantly you need to set the caching directrives in your page's header for Google+, and add an additional parameter for LinkedIn.

You can either use meta tags in the page's html code (see http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html), or in the http response headers in your webserver (see http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/).

Comment: Ok, thanks I read it. How exactly are these caching directives for google being set up?